# How to collect posts containing specific words from public Facebook users?

Tags: facebook, api, collections

I'm trying to collect posts from public Facebook users that have a certain word such as, holiday, marriage, etc. What are the best tools and approaches to collect this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an implementation like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Microsoft&type=post&fields=link,message&access_token=YOUR-API-ID|YOUR-APP-SECRET
```

It fetches results like you have requested. Make sure this call is going on at your server, so that your API ID or API Secret is not exposed.

P.S. If you do not have an app setup, visit [Facebook Dev Page](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Cheers.